# Unable to get resource from jedis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

After running my application, i am getting this error after around 5 mins.
Even though i am returning the resource after use, i keep getting this.
I have built jedis-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar from the jedis code base, since its not released yet
I had set the minIdle = 100, maxIdle=200 & maxActive=200. At the time of this exception, the connection count to redis was 122 from my application

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:42)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:442)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:360)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:40)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information. Does it work fine if you use the latest Jedis release? Can you show us the code that's calling Jedis? (There should be more to this stack trace, no?)

Comment: Have you checked your redis server is running or not. You can check it by using "ping" command in redis-cli in command line.

Comment: The redis is still up and running,i have a different application in perl that has no issue connecting with redis. Also i have written a small minature monitor that constantly monitors the connection count in redis. @kuporific i will try to share my code after filtering out the propriety parts

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that redis is still up & running ?

If not, investigate why it died.

try a redis-cli in a terminal if you can. "info" would give you more details.